# Which approach to estimate conditional probability?

Tags: probability, logistic

Hope this is clear. Suppose we have two categorical random variables and want to estimate $P(A|B)$ with data:

```
A B
0 1
1 0
. .
. .
. .
0 1
```

We could take two approaches:

(1) use a logistic regression model $$P(A=a|B=b) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta_0 + \beta_1b}}$$

(2) count $$P(A=a|B=b)=\frac{count(a,b)}{count(b)}$$

Which approach should we use?

Suppose now that B is continuous. Which should we use?

Comment: What is $f$ in the first equation?  If this isn’t homework, what’s the context?

Comment: removed $f$, was there from a prior draft.  So, it's just general. For example, if you have smoking status and want to estimate probability of cancer.  Then, if you have age and want to estimate probability of cancer (B continuous).

Comment: The two approaches should give the same answers in the discrete case.  Have you tried it?  Meanwhile, you can’t literally apply the second method in the continuous case and get something useful, assuming the values of B are distinct, as they would be in general.

Comment: I think option 1 is discrimination learning approach. Option 2 is generative (you need to generate the datum (A,B)), you estimate $P(A=a|B=b)$ by Bayes rule, and then maximize the likelihood to compute the probability. Two options use different approaches to estimate the probability, but option 1 requires to learn the parameters $\beta$. However, as The Laconic pointed that option 2 cannot be used in continuous case.

Comment: Thank you both.  @TheLaconic I haven't tried it, but my thought was the same.  You have answered my question.  YiYang is it discriminative vs. generative or parametric vs. nonparametric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two approaches should give the same answers in the discrete case.  But you can’t literally apply the second method in the continuous case and get something useful, assuming the values of B are distinct, as they would be in general.

So in the continuous case, you could use logistic regression.  Alternatively, you *could* extend approach #2 by doing the same computation over observations with *similar* values of B; for example, within some range of B.  This is a nonparametric approach, in contrast to the parametric approach of logistic regression, and it's essentially a kind of local regression.

Comment: Do you mean in the second part binning B?

Comment: For example, yes.  You can get fancier with it.